# TeamViewer on Raspberry Pi

Tags: wireless, remote, internet

I have to buy a Raspberry Pi to control a monitor remotely.

1. Can I install software like [TeamViewer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeamViewer) on Raspberry Pi?
2. Can I connect the Raspberry Pi via wireless or LAN?
3. Can I connect an Internet key to a Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. "*Can I install software like TeamViewer on Raspberry Pi?*"

Yes, use a [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) server.

2. "*Can I connect via wireless or LAN to the Raspberry Pi?*"

Yes, and you can even do both at the same time.

3. "*Can I connect an Internet key to a Raspberry Pi?*"

Yes, if you mean a USB Wi-Fi dongle.

Comment: You should probably use complete sentences.  It's hard to understand otherwise.

Comment: What if the Raspberry Pi is behind a firewall when connected to a Wi-Fi network (that is, not directly accessible on the Internet)? Can it work with VNC? An advantage of TeamViewer is that it also works if the target system is behind a firewall (they have a [rendezvous server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendezvous_protocol)).

Answer (score 5):

TeamViewer cannot be used on the Raspberry Pi at this time. They do not have a build for it.

You can install a [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) server, and that would be your simplest option. You would have no issues connecting on your LAN, however if you wanted to connect remotely, you would need to set up port forwarding.

An alternative to port forwarding would be to use a NeoRouter or Logmein Hamachi, both of which can be installed on the Raspberry Pi. (The software would also need to be installed on the machine that you are using to connect to it.)

Answer (score 3):

You can run x86 version of Teamviewer using ExaGear Desktop emulator

1. Install ExaGear Desktop (note that ExaGear isn't free and you have to obtain the license)

   ```
   tar -xvzpf exagear-desktop-rpi2.tar.gz
   sudo ./install-exagear.sh
   ```
2. Run ExaGear Desktop

   ```
   exagear
   ```
3. Download TeamViewer

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wget 
   wget http://download.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_i386.deb
   ```
4. Install TeamViewer

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_i386.deb
   sudo apt-get install -f
   ```
5. Teamviewer port for Linux is based on Wine. Raspbian use a bit different virtual memory configuration than Wine expects, so you have to patch wine

   ```
   wget http://s3.amazonaws.com/wine1.6-2g-2g/wine1.6-2g-2g.tar.gz
   tar -xzvf wine1.6-2g-2g.tar.gz
   sudo ./teamviewer-fix-2g.sh
   ```
6. Now you can run teamviewer

   ```
   teamviewer
   ```

   [image: Run Teamviewer on Raspberry Pi]

Based on [this post](https://eltechs.com/run-teamviewer-on-raspberry-pi/).

Comment: What is **teamviewer-fix-2g.sh**??  I don't know where you got this file from.

Comment: This is patched x86 wine installer to fit raspbian kernel 2g/2g memory split.

Answer (score 1):

TeamViewer can be installed on the Raspberry Pi using Eltechs Exagear. [Here](http://eltechs.com/run-teamviewer-on-raspberry-pi/) is description how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: In keeping with our [policy regarding informationless link-only answers](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538), if this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.

Answer (score 0):

http://eltechs.com/run-teamviewer-on-raspberry-pi/

Try with ExaGear!

"TeamViewer is pretty popular remote access software but unfortunately it is not available for ARM-based devices such as Raspberry Pi 2. Fortunately there is a way to run TeamViewer on Raspberry Pi 2 using ExaGear Desktop which allows to run x86 apps on Raspberry Pi 2."

Comment: That doesn't answer how to install TeamViewer on Rasp Pi.  It is a totally separate product.