# Way to have auto configured Remote GUI access to an RPi over the Internet? using something like a Remote Utilities tunnel?

Tags: remote, internet

**Options & mechanisms reviewed:**

- Not working: [Set up chrome remote desktop in raspbian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39352/set-up-chrome-remote-desktop-in-raspbian)
- Not Free: 
  [TeamViewer on RPi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23339/teamviewer-on-raspberry-pi)
  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45501/41122

  - [Run TeamViewer on Raspberry Pi - Eltechs ExaGear](https://eltechs.com/run-teamviewer-on-raspberry-pi/)
  - [The raspberry pi and Teamviewer? | element14 Community](https://www.element14.com/community/thread/21532/l/the-raspberry-pi-and-teamviewer?displayFullThread=true)

I posted a question on Software Recs to find S/W enabling "auto configured" remote access to RPi.
[Light weight alternatives to Teamviewer on Android, Raspberry type devices & Tiny linux distros?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/35635/light-weight-alternatives-to-teamviewer-on-android-raspberry-type-devices-tin)

Due to lean-ness of RPi, it seems unlikely that I'll find some software that works.

---

### Is there some way (hacky or not) to do this on the RPi the way that Remote Utlities facilitates RDP?

Now, given that [RDP / xRDP are working on RPi](http://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/raspberry-pi-remote-desktop-connection/) would it be possible to create/ leverage a mechanism or something like [Remote Utilities](https://www.remoteutilities.com/support/docs/rdp-over-id/) that facilitates **RDP via an ID mechanism / tunnel**

> **RDP-over-ID**
>
> The RDP-over-ID feature allows you to connect to a remote computer
>   over the Internet using the RDP protocol **even when the remote computer is not directly accessible due to a firewall**. Instead, an **Internet ID connection is used as an encrypted “tunnel”** to facilitate the RDP connection.
>
> This feature is invoked automatically when you try to connect in the
>   RDP mode to a remote PC using its "Internet ID" instead of the IP
>   address.

---